# Python - Multiprocessing Queue not returning result in correct order after child processes are killed

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I am iterating over a list of rules (each rule is a big boolean expression).
I intend to solve this expression using Pyeda library. Steps are 1. parsing the rule, 2. converting to BDD form, 3. Solving the rules. Steps are not important for the problem I am facing and are wrapped under the function `do_big_job` which takes `rule` to solve and a `global Queue (q)` borrowed from `multiprocessing.Manager' and not the general Queue.

I have to time out the rules which are taking too long ('time_in' seconds) to process. The `do_threading` function is taking the global `q (Queue)`, the function to be run in child processes (`do_big_job`) and an argument (rule) to be passed to `do_big_job` and `timeout_in` to control the execution of the child processes.

To my wonder I am observing that when there is a time out and a child process is killed for running for too long, then the results are coming out of order i.e. the value returned in the Queue doesn't match with the rule passed and belongs to some other earlier rule.

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there any other way of doing what I am trying to do?

Also, I have one more question, when I am performing this in a linear way and not using multiprocessing, it's taking a lot more time for processing each rule, than its taking for each rule in a separate process. What could be the explanation for that?

```
def do_threading(q,function,argument, timeout_in=1):

    # Start function as a process
    p = Process(target=function, args=(argument,q,))
    p.start()
    p.join(.1)

    if p.is_alive():
        # Wait for 'timeout_in' seconds or until process finishes
        p.join(timeout_in)

        # If thread is still active
        if p.is_alive():
            print("running... let's kill it...")

            # Terminate
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
            return False
    return True

def do_big_job(rule, q):
    # Do something with passed argument
    print("Child: ", rule)

    # heavy computation using Pyeda library
    f = expr2bdd(expr(rule))
    count = f.satisfy_count()
    solution=[]
    for i in f.satisfy_all():
        solution.append(i)

    # Putting result in the queue for exchange
    q.put([solution,count])


def main()

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()   # Initializing Queue for data exchange between processes

    solved_parts={}
    timed_out_parts={}

    for rule in rules:   # Iterating over rules and creating process for each rule
        each_rule={}

        #Creating new processes to carry out heavy computation and passing the Queue 'q' for data exchange
        processed = do_threading( q, do_big_job, rule, timeout_in=1) 

        if processed:
            r = q.get()  # Getting result from the queue

            each_rule["solution"] = r[0]
            each_rule["solution_count"] = r[1]
            each_rule["count_unique_var"]=count_unique_variables(rule)

        else:

            each_rule["solution"] = "None"
            each_rule["solution_count"] = "None"
            each_rule["count_unique_var"]=count_unique_variables(rule)

        # Putting results in 2 types of lists
        if each_rule["solution"]=="None":
            timed_out_parts[part_num]=each_rule.copy()
        else:
            solved_parts[part_num]=each_rule.copy()

main()
```

Comment: You may want to give an _executive summary_ at the top, explaining what you want to do and what are your problems. Leave the lenthy theory/explanation to the end to streamline your question, and enlarge your answer rate. [ask]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues "__Warning:__ If a process is killed using Process.terminate() or os.kill() while it is trying to use a Queue, then the data in the queue is likely to become corrupted."

Comment: @boardrider Yeah you are right. I thought that the summary would not be very clear but I should have done that. I will do it.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo That may be the case, but I never got any exception or error, just the wrong ordering afterwards.

Comment: @Shivendra Exactly. The documentation warns of corrupted data in the queue. I saw a buggy code some time ago which was forking workers after establishing connection to PostgreSQL database. The outcome was that workers where receiving results from a database but for queries sent by other workers. No error, no warning, just wrong data.

Comment: One more thing. Your code doesn't take any advantage of multiprocessing since you always wait for one worker process to terminate (either normally or by timeout) before you spawn another worker.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo
You are right, it's not taking advantage of multiprocessing. This was my first attempt at multiprocessing, I will improve the code to exploit parallel processing.
Do you know of any workarounds (with or without multiprocessing) to timeout a part of an iteration and move onto next iteration if it takes a lot of time?
Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make lots of changes to your code, for various reasons.
Some names were not defined like `part_num`.
I have omitted using the actual Pyeda library. The solution for multiprocessing is generic and what is actually happening in the worker process is not relevant for handling data flow between processes.
I also didn't try to guess where did import `expr` from.
Therefore some functions are mocked but they are not relevant for understanding parallel computation.
Mocks are commented accordingly so is the dummy input data.

The main issue with your code is that you're expecting to start workers and collect results in one loop. Forget about it whenever you're using threading or multiprocessing since the order of data coming back from workers is basically undefined. Therefore the worker is responsible to provide unambiguous information on which rule it was working on together with the result.

One more big difference is that I'm actually launching all the workers in the beginning which makes the calculation parallel actually. Then I'm collecting incoming results. Whenever the queue is empt I'm checking if all the workers returned their exit codes already which is a clear information that nothing interesting is going to happen anymore.

The master process is not responsible for timing out workers. Worker terminates itself after a timeout by `SIGALRM`. I do it this way because master process has no reliable information on when exactly the worker process entered the entry point of our Python code.

The last thing is that I'm populating `timed_out_parts` based on missing results in `solved_parts`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from multiprocessing.queues import Empty as QueueEmpty
from signal import alarm

# Following imports are only needed to mock some function
from time import sleep
from collections import namedtuple
import random

# Mock for `expr()`
def expr(rule):
    return rule

# Mock for `expr2bdd()` - sleeps randomly simulating heavy computation
def expr2bdd(expression):
    sleep(random.randint(0, 9))
    satisfied = [n for n in xrange(random.randint(0, 5))]
    def satisfy_count():
        return len(satisfied)
    def satisfy_all():
        return satisfied
    Evaluation = namedtuple('Evaluation', ('satisfy_count', 'satisfy_all'))
    return Evaluation(satisfy_count=satisfy_count, satisfy_all=satisfy_all)

# Mock for `count_unique_variables()`
def count_unique_variables(arg):
    return random.randint(0, 9)

# This function is executed in separate process - does the actual computation
def evaluate_rule(queue, part_num, rule, timeout):
    alarm(timeout)
    print 'Part: {}, Rule: {}'.format(part_num, rule)
    evaluation = expr2bdd(expr(rule))
    count = evaluation.satisfy_count()
    solution=[]
    for i in evaluation.satisfy_all():
        solution.append(i)
    queue.put([part_num, solution, count])

# Main function which starts workers and collects results
def evaluate_rules(rules, timeout=5):
    manager = Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()
    solved_parts = {}
    processes = []
    for part_num, rule in enumerate(rules):
        process = Process(target=evaluate_rule, args=(queue, part_num, rule, timeout))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
    while True:
        try:
            result = queue.get_nowait()
        except QueueEmpty:
            if all((process.exitcode is not None for process in processes)):
                break
        solved_parts[result[0]] = {
            'solution': result[1],
            'solution_count': result[2],
            'count_unique_var': count_unique_variables(rule)
        }
    timed_out_parts = {
        part_num: {
            'solution': None,
            'solution_count': None,
            'count_unique_var': count_unique_variables(rule)
        }
        for part_num, rule in enumerate(rules) if part_num not in solved_parts
    }
    return solved_parts, timed_out_parts

# Initialize `random generator` - only for mocks
random.seed()

# Dummy rules
rules = [i for i in xrange(50)]

# Fun starts here
solved_parts, timed_out_parts = evaluate_rules(rules)

# You definitely want to do something more clever with the results than just printing them
print solved_parts
print timed_out_parts
```

As for your second question: There is no golden answer for that. Differences in linear and parallel processing times are dependent on what does the worker actually do.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control all the code that handles each rule then a separate `Process` is a reliable solution to implement a timeout.

You could add the rule to the result to avoid worrying about the order. To avoid corrupting a common queue, you could use a separate pipe for each process (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, cpu_count, freeze_support
from multiprocessing.connection import wait

def do_big_job(rule, conn):
    with conn:
        # compute solution, count for the rule..
        # send the result to the parent process
        conn.send((rule, solution, count))

def main():
    jobs = {} # mapping: connection -> process
    max_workers = cpu_count() # max number of concurrent jobs
    rules = iter(rules) # make an iterator

    for rule in islice(rules, max_workers): # start initial jobs
        add_job(jobs, rule)

    while jobs:
        ready = wait(jobs, timeout)
        if not ready: # timeout and no results are ready
           rotate_job(jobs, rules) # remove old job, add a new one

        for conn in ready: # get results
            try:
                rule, solution, count = conn.recv()
            except EOFError:
                rotate_job(jobs, rules, conn)        
            else:
                print(rule, solution, count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

where `add_job()`, `rotate_job()` implement a process pool that limits number of concurrent processes and allows to kill its worker processes:

```
def add_job(jobs, rule): #XXX create class for the Pool
    r, w = Pipe(duplex=False)
    with w:
        p = Process(target=do_big_job, args=[rule, w], daemon=True)
        p.start() 
    jobs[r] = p

def rotate_job(jobs, rules, conn=None): 
    if conn is None:
       for conn in jobs:
           break

    # start next job
    for rule in rules:
        add_job(jobs, rule)
        break

    # remove timeouted job
    process = jobs.pop(conn)
    if process.is_alive():
        process.terminate()
    process.join() #NOTE: it may hang if `.terminate()` is ignored
```

The pool implementation creates a new `Process` for each job.